# mod.rewrite Multiple rules Same Directory

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I am using the following code...

```
#Fix Rewrite
Options -Multiviews

# Mod Rewrite
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

to turn `www.website.com/index.php?q=Keyword` into `www.website.com/Keyword`

Which works great....however....

I also (in the same directory) have a file called `spec.php` which accepts a `GET` variable of `eid`.

I need to also have a rule that turns `www.website.com/spec.php?eid=00000` into `www.website.com/00000` or `www.website.com/spec/00000` without actually moving `spec.php` into a subdirectory.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated, my eyes have google burn. I found some that did something similar but when I tried to match it to my situation I got problems.

Comment: "to turn `www.website.com/index.php?q=Keyword` into `www.website.com/Keyword`": that should be the other way round, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this line here

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

is matching everything, if you want to have `website.com/Keyword` work and `website.com/spec/0000` work then you need to add another condition

I think this will work

```
RewriteRule ^/spec/(.+)$ /spec.php?eid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ /index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

**What is this saying?**

First part is a regular expression, second part is the URL to map it to and the last part is the flags. In this instance we put the `/spec/` condition first so that it is hit first as the second condition will match everything else and then make sure the `[L]` flag is set as that tells mod_rewrite to stop if the current condition matches.